# Wondering if the lower version of visual studio can use the dll built using higher version of visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Have both versions of visual studio installed on a machine. I am wondering if the lower version of visual studio can use the dll built using higher version of visual studio?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and find out?

Comment: simple case works, wondering if there is exceptions in complex cases. I cannot try one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you cannot mix dlls compiled with different versions of the CRT in one program. [Here's a link to the documentation at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

As others mentioned, it works if you keep the interface simple. Don't free memory allocated with one CRT in a DLL linked to another version of the CRT, don't pass FILE* and similar around. Unfortunately, it's hard to know for sure what you can do and what you can't do.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the DLL. For example, if you create a Win32 DLL, using simple parameter types and the same calling convention, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you restrict yourself to what's called a C-style interface- only primitive types, the code that allocates any resource *must* deallocate it, and also must abstract over non-memory resources like file handles, etc. You cannot send C++ classes or objects or deallocate memory across DLL boundaries except under some extremely strict conditions.